# Python - SQL Connector: Update do not work

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, mysql-python

I want to update records in MySQL. However, I always get an error that the syntax does not work. I think it is a formatting error, however I can't manage to fix it.

Error message:

```
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''ovd' = 1 WHERE id = '16923'' at line 1
```

My code looks like:

```py
func = ['OffizierIn vom Dienst Bezirk', 'EinsatzoffizierIn']
dbFields = ["ovd", "offizier"]

x = 0
for i in func:
    el = chrome.find_element_by_id('RoleId')
    for option in el.find_elements_by_tag_name('option'):
        if option.text == i:
            option.click()
    chrome.find_element_by_id('SearchBtn').submit()
    time.sleep(2)
    tbody = chrome.find_element_by_id('SearchResults')
    for row in tbody.find_elements_by_xpath('./tr'):
        itemsEmployee = row.find_elements_by_xpath('./td')
        cursor.execute('UPDATE employees SET %s = 1 WHERE id = %s;', (dbFields[x], itemsEmployee[1].text))
    x = x + 1
```

In the first pass, the values are as in the error message: `dbFields[x] = ovd` `itemsEmplyee[1] = 16923`

The table was created as follows:

```py
cursor.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS employees (id INT NOT NULL UNIQUE, ovd BOOLEAN);')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've encountered one of the annoyances in writing dynamic database queries: *values* must be quoted, if necessary, with quotation marks, as performed by the connector package, but *table and column names*, if quoted, are quoted with backticks.  See the [MySQL rules](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifiers.html).

You need to add the column name using string formatting, then pass the value to a prepared statement:

```py
stmt = f'UPDATE employees SET `{dbFields[x]}` = 1 WHERE id = %s;'
cursor.execute(stmt, (itemsEmployee[1].text,))
```